# Que signifie le mot « balecs » dans ce contexte ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

Dans le texte de Guignol's Band, il s'agit d'un semi-délire. Le narrateur est à Londres, et il est frappé par les souvenirs de son père, sa mère, son enfance au "Passage du Vérododat" qui serait une parodie du "Passage Choiseul" à Paris.

Savez-vous que signifie le mot « **balecs** » dans ce contexte ?

«... ma jeunesse qui m'houspille encore! me relance! me misère! tout est là en bouille! qui me secoue! les gens du Passage! les **balecs**! les voisins du Vérododat! »

La traduction anglaise donne :

« My youth knocking me around again! Plaguing me! Sickening me! It's all there in a heap! Shaking me! The people from the Passage du Vérododat! **The busybodies!** The neighbours! »

Comment: Le contexte est très insuffisant. Qu'est ce qui vient avant ? après ? Je connais l'expression  [« j'men balek »](https://www.lemonde.fr/blog/correcteurs/2019/06/30/balek/) mais je doute que ça ait un rapport. Passage, Verododat, on pense à un lieu, une habitation, peut-être à rapprocher de « balcon», ça serait « ceux du balcon/ceux qui sont à leurs balcons » ? Pure spéculation en l'absence de plus de contexte. Il y a effectivement des balcons au-dessus de l'entrée de la galerie Véro-Dodat.

Comment: Dans le texte, c'est un moment de délire. Le narrateur est à Londres, et il est frappé par les souvenirs de son père, sa mère, son enfance au "Pasage du Vérododat" qui serait une parodie du "Passage Choiseul" à Paris.

Comment: Tu ne m'en dis pas plus. Par contre la [galerie Véro-Dodat](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerie_V%C3%A9ro-Dodat) existe, ce n'est pas une parodie. C'est un passage couvert de Paris. Le passage Choiseul en est un autre.

Comment: C'est une parodie par rapport à la biographie de Céline qui a vécu, en effet, au Passage Choiseul. Merci pour la précision.

Comment: Je ne sais pas quoi ajouter, je trouve "les balecs", tout de même, difficile à comprendre.

Comment: Peut-être que ce mystérieux *balecs* est une transcription phonétique de l'anglais *bollocks*...

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, peut-être... mais l'auteur maintient plusieurs mots en anglais en italique dans le texte, sans faire de modifications orthographiques. Je viens de regarder encore dans le Wikitionnaire: "De l’arabe بالك, belec (« fais attention »)". Pensez-vous que ce mot pourrait désigner les admonestations faites par un père en colère ?

Comment: L'arabe *belec* est moins vraisemblable, l'action se situe à Londres, pas à Alger, et *belec* est une phrase, pas un substantif ("les fait attention" ??). Les italiques sont une convention typographique introduite au moment de l'édition. Qu'il ait été écrit à la main ou à la machine à écrire, difficile pour l'auteur de mettre un mot en italiques à l'époque. D'autre part, on met des italiques à un mot étranger dont on conserve l'orthographe mais ici, ce serait une forme argotique francisée qui ne requiers pas d'italiques.

Comment: Merci pour votre commentaire. Vous avez raison, j'ai déjà regardé le manuscrit de Guignol's Band à la BNF, et il n'y a pas de mots indiqués en italique, mais Céline ne modifie pas les orthographies en anglais. Je sais que l'action se situe à Londres... mais le narrateur se souvient constamment de la violence de son père, c'est pourquoi "belec" comme phrase substantivée m'a paru une hypothèse plausible.

Comment: Le maintien de l'**orthographe** anglaise n'est pas systématique. On trouve ***Mammi, Mammi*** pour *Mummy, Mummy*, un ***Ouatt** !...* qui est peut-être un *What!...*. *Deux sodas **Biouty**!*, clairement *beauty*, *Fée **Bioutifoul***..

Comment: Merci beaucoup, vous avez raison !

Comment: Préciser de quel livre cela sort permet de gagner du temps dans l'analyse en éliminant d'office les hypothèse anachronique. Si c'est du Céline (qui semble occuper beaucoup de monde sur FSE), il faut le mentionner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'est de l'argot militaire qui vient de l'arabe balec. C'est une sorte d'interjection qui veut dire tire-toi, dégage, stop, n'en jetez plus, on en a assez vu etc... Ferdinand doit repenser aux fois où il s'est fait jeter du passage, les baffes, les engueulades.... on peut traduire baleks par renvois, les congédiements, licenciements, engueulades etc[image]

Comment: Un mot sur la source svp :-)

Answer (score 3):

La traduction en anglais me conforte dans l'idée que *balecs* serait issu de balcon (dans la pensée de l'auteur, bien entendu).

Céline évoque le « Passage » (la [Galerie Véro-Dodat](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerie_V%C3%A9ro-Dodat)), très semblable au [Passage Choiseul](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passage_Choiseul) où il vécut dans son enfance. [L'un](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Galerie_V%C3%A9ro-Dodat_01.jpg) comme [l'autre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passage_Choiseul#/media/Fichier:Paris_-_Passage_de_Choiseul_01.jpg) sont surmontés et entourés à leurs entrées d'appartements possédant des **balcons** où les habitants peuvent passer leur temps. La traduction en anglais reflète ceci, non pas en évoquant l'endroit où se trouvent les voisins, mais ce qu'ils font, car que fait-on perché sur son balcon ? On espionne ses voisins et ce qui se passe dans la rue. Les *balecs* ce sont ceux qui sont plantés sur leur balcon et qui n'ont rien d'autre à faire qu'à surveiller leurs voisins.